# Using multiple UITableview in Single ViewController with Custom TableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

How can I return a TableViewcell in cellForRowAtIndexPath delegate method , if I m using multiple UITableView in a Single ViewController, One TableView has Custom UITableViewCell and the other has default UITableViewCell . My problem is I m not able to cast the UITableViewCell to Custom TableViewCell type .

Code used as follows ,

```
 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        var cell:UITableViewCell?
        if tableView == self.tvCity {
            var cell:UITableViewCell?
            cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cityCellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

            let row = indexPath.row
            cell!.textLabel?.text = self.cityList[row].cityEn
                   }
        if tableView == self.tvBranchByCity {
            var cell:BranchNearMeTableViewCell?
            cell = (tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(branchCellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! BranchNearMeTableViewCell)

            let row = indexPath.row
           cell.branchName = self.branchList[row].name// here cell.branchName is not accessible.

        }

        return cell!
    }
```

Please advise . Thanks in advance.

Comment: your custom cell  is as prototype or in xib

Comment: Prototype only not using any xib @Katty

Answer (score 1):

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


        if tableView == self.tvCity {
            var cell:UITableViewCell?
            cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cityCellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

            let row = indexPath.row
            cell!.textLabel?.text = self.cityList[row].cityEn
            return cell!
                   }
        if tableView == self.tvBranchByCity {
            var cell:BranchNearMeTableViewCell?
            cell = (tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(branchCellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! BranchNearMeTableViewCell)

            let row = indexPath.row
           cell.branchName = self.branchList[row].name as! String // here cell.branchName is not accessible.
           return cell!
        }


    }
```

Comment: Thanks for a quick answer. Stil not accessible

Comment: value of type BranchNearMeTableViewCell has no member error. Actually I tried your solution before posting

Comment: working thanks alot i Just restarted Xcode .. :) thanks alot for your help

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104364/discussion-between-user2695433-and-yagnesh-dobariya).

Comment: Missing return in a function expected to return 'UITableViewCell'

Comment: Its because of the If statement, since if it wont satisfy there is no default return

Comment: Wish you posted solution as well. Gotta return default value.

Answer (score 1):

Differentiate  tables with tag

see example :

```
if tableView.tag == 2000

 {

identifier = "First Table"

 let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(identifier, forIndexPath: indexPath)

 return cell

 }

else

  {

 identifier = "Second Table"

let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(identifier, forIndexPath: indexPath)

 return cell

 }
```

Comment: Thanks Katty.. I had to restart after trying @yagnesh solution